# compiling kernel to create debian package using distcc

Tags: linux, compilation, kernel, distributed, distcc

I have used distcc for distributed compilation of several packages using **"make -j8 CC=distcc"** command.
It is working fine. But for creating debian package by compiling kernel source, we use "make-kpkg" command to build .deb file. With `make-kpkg`, i can't use "CC=distcc" (which will invoke distributed compilation).
To build I use following command:

```
fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=.<Unique Identifier> kernel-image
```

So suggest me and correct me, how can I make use of distcc in above command.

Answer (score 0):

Before you run make-kpkg

```
export CC=distcc
```

Which will set the environment variable assuming you're running bash, dash or ksh.

Comment: I tried this, it is not distributing the compilation process to other computers. With 'make -j8 CC=distcc', i was able to distribute the compilation process

Comment: @user7234 then you're out of luck or you need to modify make-kpkg to honor the CC environment variable. Or, you could try alias gcc=distcc

Comment: @user7234 welcome to stackoverflow, if the answer fix your problem or I help fix it, could accept the answer or/and upvote, perhaps also should read this http://stackoverflow.com/tour thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a masquerade directory and prepend it to `PATH` before running `make-kpkg`. The `distcc` manpage explains the setup thus:

```
mkdir /usr/lib/distcc/bin
cd /usr/lib/distcc/bin
ln -s ../../../bin/distcc gcc
ln -s ../../../bin/distcc cc
ln -s ../../../bin/distcc g++
ln -s ../../../bin/distcc c++
```

Make sure to add the masquerade directory to your `PATH` before building, so the `distcc` symlinks are found before the system compiler:

```
export PATH="/usr/lib/distcc/bin:$PATH"
fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=.<Unique Identifier> kernel-image
```

That should resolve the issues you're seeing. Using `distcc` over SSH as a normal user with `fakeroot` comes with its own bushel of problems, but that's a separate conversation.